# Is there a site on which I can run PHP code?

Tags: php

I want to run PHP code as a test without using my own webserver. Is there any site that would allow me to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow I didn't know there was this many. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[First google result](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

I think It's better to install php on you local PC

You will able to

- use functions that are restricted in sandboxes,
- configure it, as you need,
- install any extension
- see result without any stuff of site code

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful but is it possible that I can save the code that I write and get my own page that displays the result data.

Answer (score 1):

**Codepad** is a good choice. Supports multiple languages, including PHP.

http://codepad.org/

Answer (score 0):

[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/), [Codepad](http://codepad.org/), and probably many others, take your pick. For those two however, PHP 5.2 will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Another good choice:

http://writecodeonline.com/php/